# PHP check website online or offline issue

Tags: php

This works for checking whether a website is online:

```
<?php
$host = 'http://jdfhgjfdhjanmczxmcnaushdfjsa.com';
if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
        echo 'true';
fclose($socket);
}else{
    echo 'false';

}
```

But when I try to check **multiple sites**, it does not work. They all return false. Why?

```
<?php
$hosts = array();
$hosts[] = 'jdfhgjfdhjanmczxmcnaushdfjsa.com';
$hosts[] = 'google.co.il';
  $i = 0;
foreach($hosts as $host){
    $i++;
    if($socket =@ fsockopen($host[$i], 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
        echo 'true';
fclose($socket);
}else{
    echo $host.' false';

}   
}
```

Comment: You should paste the code here, so that later users can learn from your mistake even if your links go dead.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the 2nd code doesn't work is that you are not accessing the hosts correctly

Change

```
if($socket = @fsockopen($host[$i]...)
```

To

```
if($socket = @fsockopen($host...)
```

You don't need the `$i` index. You can get rid of it altogether.

**Addendum**

You noted when you first posted that calling in a loop wasn't working but calling one domain worked. The fix above is the solution to your original question.  What you're facing is a different problem: You missed it because you added the error suppression operator `@` in front of your function call. Removing it shows you the problem:

> fsockopen() has been disabled for security reasons

Online sandboxes disable `fsockopen`, so you cannot rely on their output to determine whether that code works. By the way it's a bad idea to use error suppression, particularly in development.

Comment: No its not the issue,i have updated the code.. see example 2.you saw the old link because every one editing my question every 2 seconds.

Comment: You're mixing issues. I resolved your initial issue. Take a look at what I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're combining a **for** and a **foreach** loop a bit there - if you use **foreach**, you don't need to worry about the `$i` variable at all. In this case, you're checking the hosts array by the `$i` index, but reporting based on the `$host` variable, which is probably confusing things.

The following works ok for me:

```
<?php
$hosts = array();
$hosts[] = 'jdfhgjfdhjanmczxmcnaushdfjsa.com';
$hosts[] = 'google.co.il';

foreach($hosts as $host){
    if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {
        echo 'true';
        fclose($socket);
    }
    else {
        echo $host.' false';
    }
}
```

Also, bear in mind that most online sandboxes will have functions like `fsockopen` disabled, to prevent them being used maliciously, so the example URLs given above are likely never going to work. From the one in your question:

> This script works with a whitelist of functions. All functions that do not require disk, system or network access are whitelisted, others blacklisted. Max execution time is set to 3 seconds.

Comment: No its not the issue,i have updated the code.. see example 2.you saw the old link because every one editing my question every 2 seconds.

Comment: Which bit do you mean when you say "it's not the issue"? Your example2 still mixes the two loop types, and the last part of my answer explains why this type of code will very rarely work in a sandbox. What I've posted works fine here.

Comment: Read again,go to example 2,and there is no mixed loops.still not working with multiple urls

Comment: And not its not working,check sandbox they both false

Comment: Please read my comment and the last sentence in my answer. That sandbox, like most others, does not support the `fsockopen` function - it doesn't matter what URL you use, it's always going to return false.

Comment: In my server fsockopen is enabled and they both false.only if i try one by one its working no in loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    <?php
function Visit($url){
       $agent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)";$ch=curl_init();
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url );
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
       curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt ($ch,CURLOPT_VERBOSE,false);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
       curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
       $page=curl_exec($ch);
       //echo curl_error($ch);
       $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
       curl_close($ch);
       if($httpcode>=200 && $httpcode<300) return true;
       else return false;
}
if (Visit("http://www.google.com"))
       echo "Website OK"."n";
else
       echo "Website DOWN";
?>
```

Try using google to find solutions. This code worked for me and I found it on https://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/check-if-website-is-available/

Comment: @Rovog you can make a array and call the function multiple times such as:


`$list = array("site","site2","site3");

foreach($list as $sites){
if (Visit($sites)){
       echo "Website OK"."n";
}else{
       echo "Website DOWN";
}
}`

Comment: Oh okay. Said you tried with multiple urls not with a foreach. My bad then

Comment: Yea its keep return all true while one of them is false. if i try one by one not inside foreach its working good.